# How can i clear previous error log in Testcomplete

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

How can i clear previous error log in Testcomplete
 as the object is visible after some time. I am using Do until loop to wait and get the object, the error is logged when the object is not visible.

But the object is visible after some time loop is ran. Can i clear the previous error logs, or do i have any other solution for it. Please help...
Thanks

Comment: Can you post here the exact code and the text of the error? Right now, information is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the objects Exists property as it does not throw error messages (afaik). A quick draft (untested):

```
while not Aliases.Device.Mapped.Name.Of.Object.Exists
    ' Wait
wend
```